# pipe data from 1 stream to 2 different streams depending on the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I have 1 stream that has data coming that is prefixed with 2 different prefixes. let us say 1 and 0. I want all data that is prefixed with 1 to get piped only to stream A and 0 to stream B.

I have thought of just using 2 transforms that only allows data to pass if it has the correct prefix. I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing this.

```
//an idea

//transformA is a transform that only pushes data that is prefixed with 1
//transformB is a transformt hat only pushes data that is prefixed with 2
incomingStream.pipe(transformA).pipe(destinationA)
incomingStream.pipe(transformB).pipe(destinationB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for-await` and `if` maybe?

```
for await (const chunk of incomingStream) {
    if(chunk.startsWith("1")) {
        destinationA.write(transformA(chunk));
        continue;
    }

    if(chunk.startsWith("2")) {
        destinationB.write(transformB(chunk));
        continue;
    }

    destinationElse.write(chunk);
}
```